# .htaccess mode rewrite does not affect page url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know it was answered on all over the internet, but non of this helped me.
I looked even here, didnt help me.

I need to have clear urls

I have this url
http://localhost/projekt-vb/index.php?page=example

I need address to be like this localhost/projekt-vb/example

I used this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But for me it didnt solve anything.
I know its everywhere but nothing help cant someone write me what I am doing wrong. I am getting mad from it

My file tree is :

```
projekt-vb/
   admin/
   core/
   modules/
   template/
       cont/
       css/
       imgs/
       example.php
   .htaccess
   index.php
```

All those files ?page=example  lets say, will be placed in template/cont/

Comment: Personally, I prefer putting this sort of stuff directly in the config instead of inside the IfModule tags. It is possible that you have forgotten to load the module, so your config loads, doesn't behave how you want, and never gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original URL: http://localhost/projekt-vb/index.php?page=example

Rewrite URL: localhost/projekt-vb/example

Place you **.htaccess** file under the folder **projekt-vb**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projekt-vb/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When you user url rewrite in localhost, you have to specify folder name on which your project exists, Caused in htdocs or www folder we are you that is our public_html as live website.

So you have to tell folder for you base path for url rewrite.

You file structure must be like this.

```
projekt-vb/
   admin/
   core/
   modules/
   template/
       cont/
       css/
       imgs/
       example.php
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

Now in index.php, you can get page as per the below

```
$pagename=$_GET["page];
```

Comment: Hi I tried but didnt helped

Comment: I change my question to be more specify

Comment: check url rewrite is working or not, please change your .htaccess path, it not in template folder. Its on project-vb folder. Check my answer in detail and place file as per i suggest to you